# AJAX request not registering on submit from form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an AJAX submit handler for a form in my html, but when I click submit, the AJAX request is not registered. But I can't see what is wrong with my syntax, as it was copied straight from a source doing the exact same thing.

Here is the html **updated**:

```
<form id="initialPost" action="initialProgress.php" method="post">
          <table class="progressTable2">
            <tr>
                <td>Chosen a city?
                    <input type="checkbox" name="foundCity" value="cityIsChecked" />
                </td>
                <td>Found accommodation?
                    <input type="checkbox" name="foundAccom" value="accomIsChecked"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Set up a bank account?
                    <input type="checkbox" name="foundBank" value="bankIsChecked"/>
                </td>
                <td>Sorted CAF?
                    <input type="checkbox" name="gotCaf" value="cafIsChecked"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='2'>
                    <input type="submit" class="popupButton"/></submit>
                </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </form>
```

and the JS **updated**:
*the alert is in there to check if it enters the function and it doesn't call*

```
$(window).ready(function(){
        $("#initialPost").submit(function(e) {
              alert("submitRegistered");

              e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
              var url = "initialProgress.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.
              console.log($("#initialPost"));

              $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: $("#initialPost"),
                success: function(data) {
                  checkboxFunction();
                  window.location = '#';
                }
              });

        });
    });
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You are probably missing a .serialize() at the end of the data definition of your Ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jquery loaded in head section you must write your code in document ready.
Have a look at the below snippet

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#initialPost").on('submit',function(e) {
            alert("submitRegistered");

            e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
            var url = "initialProgress.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.
            console.log($("#initialPost"));

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: $("#initialPost"), 
                success: function(data)
                {

                    checkboxFunction();
                    window.location='#';
                }
            });

    });

});
```

Below is your fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/rajeshsnadar/rm1pgLt3/

Comment: That still didn't work. Please see my updated code above where I removed some of the html code which may have been causing problems

Comment: Yes I saw and copied directly to mine. Must be something else in my html or something.

Comment: use the one that i have mentioned in the snippet.

Comment: The problem was, along with not having it in a document ready function, I had two forms with the same id. That's why it wasn't calling